# how I use the facebook API in my php code?

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

hii Friends,

I am working on widgets.I want to build facebook application in small widget.
so how I use the facebook API in my php code.
please provide the guidline.

please...
Help me..

Comment: Your question isn't really a question, nor is your explanation of your expected outcome detailed.

Comment: I would have thought that if you had the skill to write a CakePHP application, this would be straightforward. You will only learn by researching and doing, not by asking someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/facebook/facebook-php-tutorial/

read this and ask some more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

developer.facebook.com. is a great resource but if you are looking for some to tell you how thinkdiff.net has some step by step tutorials.

Comment: I just wanna use functionality of face book.

Comment: when I am click log in from hear to connect to face book A/C. Fetch data and view on My own UI.